# PYODBC connection string - using converters when calling information

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

I have the following Python Pandas excel read in statement which utilizes a 'converter' to change an 'ID' from a number type to a string type.  I set this up this way in order to make merging dataframes easier later on in the code.  I have now gotten access to the DB to pull data directly.  Is anyone familiar with adding in a converter into the cnxn line with PYODBC?

```
Excel
df = pd.read_excel('c:/Users/username/Desktop/filename.xlsx', sheet_name="sheet1", converters={'ID':str})

PYODBC
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=server.name.com,xxxxx;UID=user;PWD=password; Trusted_Connection=yes')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute(script)

columns = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
data = cursor.fetchall()
df = pd.read_sql_query(script, cnxn)
```

As of right now, utilizing excel works exactly how I want it to and I am fairly confident I can convert the series type later on in the code, but I am wondering if it can be done when it is called/imported directly from SQL.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you looked at [add_output_converter](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyodbc/wikis/Connection.wiki#add_output_converter). Something like `cnxn.add_output_converter(sqltype, func)`

Comment: @Chris - The problem with that approach would be that defining an output converter function to map `int` to `str` would do that for all `int` columns, not just one. There has been some discussion about enhancing pyodbc to support column-specific output converter functions, but that is still in the "ideas" stage.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I appreciate your input and help!  i am able to use df['ID'] = df['ID'].astype(str) and it works just as well, i just didnt know if PYODBC had similar functionality as pd.read_excel() - thanks again for your help!!

Comment: @John - `read_sql` et al. in pandas do not have `converter` options, presumably because database columns are (usually) strictly typed so it knows what data type to expect. I suspect that you'll need to convert the column after importing.